# set bordercolor for image which is in array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have images in an array, and when I display those images on view, it should appear with the border.  How do I set the border color?

```
for(UIImage *img in imagesArray)

{

//for bordercolor

}
```

Comment: add quartzcore framework and then add borderwidth and bordercolor for imageview layer.

Comment: Are all your images of the same size? and is that same as imageview size?

Comment: yes, all images are in same size and same as imageview size.

Comment: your question is not clear, actually are you loading a single imageview with an image from an array one at a time? or you want to load as many image views as the number of images in the array, altogether?

Comment: In imagesarray i have some images and i want to display all those images with the bordercolor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Add `QuartzCore.framework` framework in your project from **Build Phases => Link Binary with Libraries => Add button(+)** and after import its file in your class like bellow...

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and use bellow code for set color..

```
yourImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
yourImageView.layer.borderColor= [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

**UPDATE:**

```
-(IBAction)lockword:(id)sender { 
   for (UIImage *img3 in imagesArray) { 
     UIImageView *imgview1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img3];
    imgview1.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    imgview1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    [imgview1 release];
    // your other code write here
    // Add this UIImageView as a subview of your view with its frame...
 } 
}
```

Comment: what you mean ?? not got it :(

Comment: @SwethaReddy hey see when you display that image on any view at that time set this code ...

Comment: whenever i clicked on the some button then all images in array must appear with the border color.

Comment: -(IBAction)lockword:(id)sender                                                         {                                                                     for (UIImageView *img3 in imagesArray)
{                                                           //setbordercolor.                                                         }
}

Comment: no no post whole method like..-(IBAction)btnCameraMEnu_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    UIImageView *imgview1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]];
    imgBackBoard.image = imgview1.image;
    imgBackBoard.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 694.0);yourImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
yourImageView.layer.borderColor= [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    [imgview1 release];
}

Comment: yes i got it but see for display UIImage you use UIImageView right?? the just set this above code to that UIImageView and you will see border on your image....

Comment: Did u got that,For me exception is there

Comment: [UIImage layer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x719b350
2013-04-17 11:49:20.072 RandomFunctionGenerator[1081:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage layer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x719b350'
this is the exception i got.

Comment: you import this file in your ViewController.m file #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>??

Comment: ohh hey... here you set border color to UIImage not to UIImageView... here problem is with UIImage add the UIImage in UIImageView and set layer to UIImageView...

Comment: @SwethaReddy see my above answer.... i set layer to UIImageView not to UIImage and also if array have UIImage then do something like above .. i will Update answer...

Comment: if i set to UIImage then there is not property called layer,borderwidth at all.

Comment: no UIImage have not property like that so we use UIImageView which have these type of property..

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

[imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow editing the border color property of your imageview, you need to add **Quartzcore framework**
Add it from :  **Link Binary with Libraries option** and then write the following code where you want to change the border color :

```
[imageview.layer setBorderWidth:2.0]; // set the border width to any value you want so that your bordercolor would appear accordingly

[imageview.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor].CGColor]; // set the color to whatever background color you want to set to your image
```